# Inner join with three tables with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables. `Table 1` and `Table 2`, I can join with `User name` and `Table 3`, I can join `Table 1`'s `ip` column.

Here is the sample Sql Script I written.

```
SELECT R.[First Time], L.[USER], R1.[Destination Port] , L1.[IP Address]  AS 'L1 IP Address',L2.[IP Address] AS 'L2 IP Address'
  FROM [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[LookUp_15_75] AS L 
 INNER JOIN [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[Raw_15_244] AS R 
    ON L.[USER]=R.[Source User]
INNER JOIN [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[Raw_15_246] AS R1 
    ON L.[IP]=R1.[Source IP]
LEFT  JOIN [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[LookUp_15_76] AS L1 ON R1.[Destination IP]=L1.[IP Address] 
LEFT  JOIN [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[LookUp_15_77] AS L2 ON R1.[Destination IP]=L2.[IP Address] 
 WHERE L.[USER]='support.treasury1' 
   AND R.[Source User]='support.treasury1'
```

This is the output I am getting.

[image: Getting]

This is the output I am Expecting.

[image: Expected Result]

This is the three table structure with data

[image: Table Structure and data]

Comment: Where does support.treasury2 and support.treasury3 come from?

Comment: @Vashi I have updated my question

Comment: How come 13:14 has one entry and 13:55 has two entries? What is the logic?

Comment: How are *we* (and thus SQL Server) meant to know *which* `First time` values correspond with *which* `Destination Port` values?

Comment: @Vashi First Time is coming from Table 1(Raw_15_244), we can map that table with Table two(LookUp_15_75) with USER, the Port No I will get from Table 3(Raw_15_246) we can link this table to table 1 with IP or Source IP

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's what I am searching for. There is no more links to map this three table,hope I have explained everything.

Comment: You seem to have one-to-many relationship which is why you are ending up with duplicates. I think you need to add some more conditions in the join clause. Would need sample entries for all three tables to get a better picture.

Comment: @Vashi I have added the tables structure along with data, hope you are clear now

Comment: I understood the joins and can see there is a one-to-many relationship. I don't understand the last 2 rows of your expected output. How are you expecting 13:14 to have one entry and 13:55 to have two entries? Can you explain?

Comment: Well, you apparently have insufficient data in your tables to produce the result set you're asking for in any *logical* fashion. Either there are other tables containing data that does help to contextualize the data you're showing us or you may as well just hard-code the result set. We can't fix this for you.

Comment: @Vashi ,@Damien_The_Unbeliever  I did some research and I find out one relation with two table, I have updated the question again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `group by`;

```
 SELECT   R.[First Time], L.[USER], R1.[Destination Port] 
FROM [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[LookUp_15_75] AS L 
INNER JOIN  [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[Raw_15_244]  AS R ON L.[USER]=R.[Source User]
INNER JOIN [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[Raw_15_246] AS R1 ON L.[IP]=R1.[Source IP]
group by R.[First Time], L.[USER], R1.[Destination Port]
```

Comment: No.i need the result with three column I have specified in the second image

Comment: Please define "Its not working" and provide more details to us. It is the only way to help you.

Comment: By using your query I am getting the same result i have already, Here I need only three rows of out put. For port 3389 I need the first time as 12/28/2017  1:14:00,  for Port 22 I need the First Time as 12/28/2017  1:55:46 and the Port 4100 I need the First time as 12/28/2017  1:55:46. Hope you are clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible conditions for this. First, you can try the different unique key from the table that mentioned above.

Second, you should try `DISTINCT`. The code will be more likely close to this :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT R.[First Time], L.[USER], R1.[Destination Port] 
 FROM [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[LookUp_15_75] AS L 
 INNER JOIN [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[Raw_15_244] AS R ON L.[USER]=R.[Source User]
 INNER JOIN [SAPA_SOCTemp_v1].[dbo].[Raw_15_246] AS R1  ON L.[IP]=R1.[Source IP]
 WHERE L.[USER]='support.treasury1' AND R.[Source User]='support.treasury1'
 ORDER BY R.[First Time]
```

If it still doesn't help. You should give us more detail about the logic for those tables above.